# Magento 2.2.2 - how to remove company and zipcode from billing address from checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, billing-address, checkout-page

I would like to remove postcode and company from the billing address showing in second step [#payment] of checkout page.

copied `checkout_index_index`.xml file from vendor and placed in theme folder `checkout_index_index`.xml is as follows:

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment</item>
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="billing-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                                            
                                                            <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">                                                             
                                                                <item name="visible"                                                                xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="company" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="visible"                                                                xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

When removed `pub/static/frontend/ var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed` and run below CLI commands.

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

i do not see changes to Billing Address fields. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok +1 because I didn't know i could abbreviate commands O.O

Answer (score 3):

You can remove `Company` from the **Magento dashboard**. Go to

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Name and
>   Address Options

But if you want to remove them from the layout file just put:

```
<item name="company" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
</item>
```

Comment: @Adrizan i had removed the city by using your code.. but it shows the error as city is required on shipping address in payment method selection step. please help me solve this error.